Unable to poll for events using crossterm when spawned as a NodeJS child process: "Failed to initialize input reader"
I want to start a Rust terminal user interface I've made using crossterm which needs to handle keyboard input as a NodeJS child process. This works fine when I directly run the Rust program, but results in the runtime error "Failed to initialize input reader" when spawned as a child process from Node.
Minimal reproducible example:
index.js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const runMinimalCrossterm = () => {
  const rustProcess = spawn('cargo', ['run', '--bin', 'poll'], {
    cwd: '/project/path',
    stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
  });

  rustProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`Rust says: ${data}`);
  });

  rustProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`Rust error: ${data}`);
  });

  rustProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`Rust process exited with code ${code}`);
  });

  if (rustProcess.stdin) {
    rustProcess.stdin.write('q\n');
    rustProcess.stdin.end();
  } else {
    console.error("Failed to initialize stdin for the Rust process");
  }
};

runMinimalCrossterm();

main.rs
use crossterm::event::{self, Event, KeyCode};
use crossterm::terminal::{enable_raw_mode, disable_raw_mode};
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    enable_raw_mode().expect("Failed to enable raw mode");
    println!("Polling for events. Press 'q' to exit.");

    loop {
        match event::poll(Duration::from_secs(10)) {
            Ok(true) => {
                match event::read() {
                    Ok(Event::Key(key_event)) => {
                        println!("Event: {:?}", key_event);
                        if key_event.code == KeyCode::Char('q') {
                            println!("Exiting...");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Ok(event) => {
                        println!("Event: {:?}", event);
                    }
                    Err(e) => {
                        eprintln!("Error reading event: {}", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            Ok(false) => {
                println!("No events polled within timeout.");
            }
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Failed to poll event: {}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    disable_raw_mode().expect("Failed to disable raw mode");
    Ok(())
}

Running index.js will result in this output:
Rust error:      Running `target/debug/poll`

Rust says: Polling for events. Press 'q' to exit.

Rust error: Failed to poll event: Failed to initialize input reader

Rust process exited with code 0

While running main.rs directly results in output:
Polling for events. Press 'q' to exit.
q
Event: KeyEvent { code: Char('q'), modifiers: KeyModifiers(0x0), kind: Press, state: KeyEventState(0x0) }
Exiting...


Couple questions: Do you want this to open a terminal in a new window, and does this do that? Do you want the user to be able to interact with the terminal? Or do you only want it to get input via rustProcess.stdin as you are doing now?

After some initial input via rustProcess.stdin I'll like the Rust process to assume control and handle user keyboard input for an interactive terminal interface and then return control back to the NodeJS process upon exiting with some final output data.

Console applications communicate with the terminal they're running in through escape sequences: invisible character sequences that the app prints on stdout and to which the terminal replies by writing on stdin. Since your JS code intercepts stdout and stdin, you will need to handle these escape sequences to make sure they're passed properly.
